# FirebaseUI: How to access object at indexPath during segue when using FUIIndexTableViewDataSource?

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, segue, firebaseui

I am using FUIIndexTableViewDataSource as explained on https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseDatabaseUI.

**I want to show a detail view controller when an item is tapped, but I don't know how to get the reference, key or data when preparing for the segue.**

My code:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                // HELP: How do I access the firebase reference, index, and data from here?
            }
        }
    }
```

And in a setupDatabase() function I have set up the data source.

```
self.dataSource = self.tableView.bind(
    toIndexedQuery: chatKeysRef,
    data: chatDataRef,
    delegate: self,
    populateCell:  {
        (tableView, indexPath, dataSnapshot) in

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Chat", for: indexPath);

        if (dataSnapshot == nil) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "";
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "";
            return cell;
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = "hello world"

        if (dataSnapshot!.hasChild("most_recent_message")) {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dataSnapshot?.childSnapshot(forPath: "most_recent_message").value as? String;
        }

        return cell;
});
```

FUIIndexTableViewDataSource doesn't seem to have any public properties or methods that would help me: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseDatabaseUI/FUIIndexTableViewDataSource.h

The Readme.md makes reference to FUIDataSource but that seems not to be present in FUIIndexTableViewDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Data for the selected row can be read like this

```
let snapshot: DataSnapshot = self.dataSource.items[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a property of FUIIndexTableViewDataSource, right?